# Users can claim "/story/current" for their personal Developer Story

Tags: bug, developer-story, hyperlinks

While experimenting with /current, I found that [stackoverflow.com/users/story](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/current) redirects to the current user's Developer Story as expected, but stackoverflow.com/users/story/current led to a *404 Error Page*.

I went to my Developer Story Preferences and, to my surprise, **I was able to register [stackoverflow.com/story/current](https://stackoverflow.com/story/current) as my own personal Developer Story URL.**

For reference

- [**stackoverflow.com/users/story/current**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/current): Current user's Developer Story
- [**stackoverflow.com/story/current**](https://stackoverflow.com/story/current): My *personal* Developer Story

**Is /current meant to be claimable by individual users? Or is this an unintended feature?**

Comment: Related MSE: [Inconsistent support for /current](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/298748/351462)

Comment: I don't see why not. `/story` is a permalink path that never looks up *your* user, only the user specified by the slug. If someone really wants to register the slug "current" then *shrugs* whatever. (To clarify: `/story/current` will *never* reach *your* story regardless of whether "current" gets disallowed.)